# Use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() to get assembly from other class library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic-class-loaders

I use entity framework to map classes in database, in my `ObjectContext` class :

```
 var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
            foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
            {
                dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
            }

            //Replace with ....
            //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityMap());
```

Above code get all class `typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>)`.
If my 'EntityMap' classes in the same class library with my object context, it's OK, But If my `map classes` I wrote in a separate class library that does not work. `Map classes` can not be identified on `ObjectContext`.

Comment: There may be other ways to resolve this; however, in the past, I've added another parameter to the method containing the hard coded `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` that takes in an `Assembly` parameter containing the types. The `Assembly` is then passed in from the consuming assembly.

Comment: Thanks @MetroSmurf, can you explain more?

Comment: Extract out the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` from `var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()` to a parameter in the containing method so that it becomes: `var typesToRegister = assemblyParamter.GetTypes()`. Then simply pass the Assembly reference with the types as the parameter for `assemblyParameter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{ 
    assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
                       .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
    foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
    {
        dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
    }
}
```

That should get you all the loaded assemblies instead of just the current one.

Comment: i can't find `.GetTypes()` , are you sure that code is correct.

Comment: This code throw an exception : An exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Comment: I suspect there is nothing wrong with my code. Perhaps one of your assemblies could not be loaded. I am guessing it is missing a reference or dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing this to:

```
var typesToRegister = typeof(MapClass).Assembly.GetTypes()
                      .....
```

where `MapClass` is one of the classes that inherits from `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` that is in the other assembly.

Comment: Thanks @argaz,But what is typeof(MapClass)!!?? i want found every class that `type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>) ` what is MapClass

Comment: I meant just one of the classes that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration<T>

Comment: Why not? pretty sure that it solves the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` issue by giving you the correct assembly.

Comment: can you post the code that isn't working and the exception that you're getting?